# error: invalid operands to binary ^ (have ‘double’ and ‘double’) - I'm not trying to use ^ as a power operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, television

I've been looking for an answer for this but could not find it. I'm not trying to use ^ as a power operator.

Here's my problem.
I'm trying to reproduce an interleaver from a digital TV standard (physical layer protocol). It is a project for school.
Here's the code I have so far in C:

```
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int Mmax = 32768; 
    int Nr = log10(Mmax)/log10(2);
    printf("Nr = %i \n",Nr);

    int Lfm = 42; 

    int i,j,k,l; 

    // Create array R'i 
    unsigned char Rli[Mmax][Nr];
    for (i = 0; i < Mmax; i++)
        memset(Rli[i], 0, sizeof(unsigned char)*(Nr));

    for (i = 0; i < Mmax; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j < Nr; j++)
        {
            if(i == 0 || i == 1)
            {
                Rli[i][j] = 0;
            }

            else if(i == 2)
            { 
                Rli[i][j] = 0;
                if(j == Nr - 2)
                    Rli[i][j] = 1;
            }

            else
            {
                Rli[i][j+1] = Rli[i-1][j]; 
            }
        }

        if(i > 2)
        {
            Rli[i][1] = (((Rli[i-1][14] ^ Rli[i-1][13] ) ^ Rli[i-1][12] ) ^ Rli[i-1][2]);
        }
        Rli[i][0] = 0;
    }

    // wire permutation for array R'i - creates array Ri

    unsigned char Ri[Mmax][Nr];
    for (i = 0; i < Mmax; i++)
        memset(Ri[i], 0, sizeof(unsigned char)*(Nr));   

    for (i = 0; i < Mmax; i++)
    {
        Ri[i][1] = Rli[i][8]; //Rli[i][7];
        Ri[i][2] = Rli[i][9]; //Rli[i][8];
        Ri[i][3] = Rli[i][14]; //Rli[i][13];
        Ri[i][4] = Rli[i][4]; //Rli[i][3];
        Ri[i][5] = Rli[i][6]; //Rli[i][5];
        Ri[i][6] = Rli[i][13]; //Rli[i][12];
        Ri[i][7] = Rli[i][3]; //Rli[i][2];
        Ri[i][8] = Rli[i][2]; //Rli[i][1];
        Ri[i][9] = Rli[i][12]; //Rli[i][11];
        Ri[i][10] = Rli[i][5]; //Rli[i][4];
        Ri[i][11] = Rli[i][10]; //Rli[i][9];
        Ri[i][12] = Rli[i][11]; //Rli[i][10];
        Ri[i][13] = Rli[i][1]; //Rli[i][0];
        Ri[i][14] = Rli[i][7]; //Rli[i][6];
    }

    // Offset generator Gk

    int Gmax = floor(Lfm/2);
    unsigned char Gk[Gmax][Nr];
    for (i = 0; i < Gmax; i++)
        memset(Gk[i], 0, sizeof(unsigned char)*Nr-1);

    for (k = 0; k < Gmax; k++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < Nr; j++)
        {
            if(k == 0)
            { 
                Gk[k][j] = 1; 
            }

            else
            { 
                Gk[k][j+1] = Gk[k-1][j];
            }
        } 

        if(k > 0)
        { 
            Gk[k][0] = ( Gk[k-1][14] ^ Gk[k-1][13] );
        }

    }

    // interleaving sequence

    int Ndata = 26303; // numero de data 
    unsigned char Hl[Ndata];
    double H1[Ndata], H2[Ndata];
    memset(Hl, 0, sizeof(unsigned char)*Ndata);
    memset(H1, 0, sizeof(double)*Ndata);
    memset(H2, 0, sizeof(double)*Ndata);

    int p,indice;

    // loop from page 107 of the physical layer protocol.
    for (i = 0; i < Lfm; i++) 
    {
        for (k = 0; k < Mmax; k++) 
        {
            p = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < Nr; j++) // sum
            {
                if(j >= 0 && j <= Nr - 2)
                    H1[p] += Ri[k][j]*pow(2,j);
                else if(j >= 0 && j <= Nr - 1)
                    {
                    indice = floor(i/2);
                    H2[p] += Gk[indice][j]*pow(2,j);
                    }
            }
    /*****/ Hl[p] = ((i % 2)*pow(2,Nr-1) + H1[p] ) ^ H2[p]; /*****/
            if (Hl[p] < Ndata)
                p += 1;
        }
    }
```

the line between the /*****/ in the end generates an error when I try to compile.

```
freqint.c:146:43: error: invalid operands to binary ^ (have ‘double’ and ‘double’)

        Hl[p] = ((i % 2)*pow(2,Nr-1) + H1[p] ) ^ H2[p];
```

I want to do the XOR operation there, but I can't get it right.

I'm taking this from [here](http://atsc.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/A322-2016-Physical-Layer-Protocol.pdf).

the interleaving sequence is on the bottom of page 107

How do I write my code to avoid that error message and still do an XOR?

Comment: That one the guy wants to use the operand ^ as a power operator. Not what I need :(

Comment: Why not cast the values to integer types before performing the XOR operation?  Are you expecting them to have non-zero fractional components?

Comment: you're being pretty sloppy with mixing floating point and integer operations.  Did you get Nr=15 like it's supposed to?  If so, you got lucky, because `log10(Mmax)/log10(2)` is inexact and will round down.   At the bottom, don't say `pow(2,Nr-1)` -- that produces a double and is pretty expensive.  Say `1<<(Nr-1)`, which produces an int and is very fast.

Comment: And throughout the whole thing you don't need to use any doubles at all.  floor(i/2) == (i>>1).  pow(2,j) == 1<<j, etc...    Then your H1[] and H2[] can be int[].

Comment: You could avoid being harmed by rounding error in your computation of `Nr` by computing it like so: `log10(Mmax + 0.5) / log10(2)`, at least as long as the expected result is not more than about 50.  On the other hand, in your particular code there's no reason to *compute* `Nr` at all; if `Mmax` is always 32768 then you might as well just write `Nr = 15`.

Comment: Thank you guys! I was able to undestand with your comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, the `^` operator can't be used on a `double`, however you don't need to use `double`.

You're using two functions which return a `double`, namely `pow` and `floor`.

Each time you call `pow`, you pass `2` for the base.  Raising 2 to a power can be done much more efficiently by left shifting the value `1` by the exponent.

Similarly, each time you call `floor` you're dividing an integer value by `2`.  Since integer division automatically drops the remainder of division (assuming you're working only with positive values), the call to `floor` doesn't buy you anything.

So change all instances of `pow(2,x)` to `(1 << x)`, and change all instances of `floor(x/2)` to `(x/2)`.  Then you can declare `H1` and `H2` as arrays of `unsigned int` and you will be able to use the XOR operator `^`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you @dbush !